# MD5 mismatch when PXE booting with cobbler

Tags: ubuntu, installation, mirroring, pxe

I am working on PXE booting on clients from one master node which has cobbler service on it. I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 and this is the preseed file I am using for ubuntu installation.

```
# Ubuntu Server Quick Install 
# by Dustin Kirkland <kirkland@ubuntu.com>
#  * Documentation: http://bit.ly/uquick-doc

d-i     debian-installer/locale string en_US.UTF-8
d-i     debian-installer/splash boolean false
d-i     console-setup/ask_detect        boolean false
d-i     console-setup/layoutcode        string us
d-i     console-setup/variantcode       string 
d-i     netcfg/get_nameservers  string 
d-i     netcfg/get_ipaddress    string 
d-i     netcfg/get_netmask      string 255.255.255.0
d-i     netcfg/get_gateway      string 
d-i     netcfg/confirm_static   boolean true
d-i     clock-setup/utc boolean true
d-i     partman-auto/method string regular
d-i     partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i     partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i     partman/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i     partman/choose_partition        select Finish partitioning and write changes to disk
d-i     partman/confirm boolean true
d-i     partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true 
d-i     partman/default_filesystem string ext3
d-i     clock-setup/utc boolean true
d-i     clock-setup/ntp boolean true
d-i     clock-setup/ntp-server  string ntp.ubuntu.com
d-i     base-installer/kernel/image     string linux-server
d-i     passwd/root-login       boolean false
d-i     passwd/make-user        boolean true
d-i     passwd/user-fullname    string ubuntu
d-i     passwd/username string ubuntu
d-i     passwd/user-password-crypted    password        
d-i     passwd/user-uid string 
d-i     user-setup/allow-password-weak  boolean false
d-i     user-setup/encrypt-home boolean false
d-i     passwd/user-default-groups      string adm cdrom dialout lpadmin plugdev sambashare
d-i     apt-setup/services-select       multiselect security
d-i     apt-setup/security_host string security.ubuntu.com
d-i     apt-setup/security_path string /ubuntu
d-i     debian-installer/allow_unauthenticated  string false
d-i     pkgsel/upgrade  select safe-upgrade
d-i     pkgsel/language-packs   multiselect 
d-i     pkgsel/update-policy    select none
d-i     pkgsel/updatedb boolean true
d-i     grub-installer/skip     boolean false
d-i     lilo-installer/skip     boolean false
d-i     grub-installer/only_debian      boolean true
d-i     grub-installer/with_other_os    boolean true
d-i     finish-install/keep-consoles    boolean false
d-i     finish-install/reboot_in_progress       note 
d-i     cdrom-detect/eject      boolean true
d-i     debian-installer/exit/halt      boolean false
d-i     debian-installer/exit/poweroff  boolean false
d-i     pkgsel/include string openssh-server
d-i     mirror/country string manual
d-i mirror/http/hostname string 147.xxx.xxx.xxx
d-i mirror/http/directory string /cobbler/repo_mirror/trusty-x86_64
```

I have configured last two lines so that clients can get distributions and packages from the local mirror I have made in the master node. There are two problems with the installation.

First is that the installer tries to look at

```
/cobbler/repo_mirror/trusty-x86_64/dists/trusty/main/debian-installer
```

instead of

```
/cobbler/repo_mirror/trusty-x86_64/dists/trusty/main/
```

for dists file.

I am not sure why the installer is appending debian-installer after "main" path.

Secondly, even if I symlink files under main/ to be also under debian-installer, it gives me MD5 mismatch on Packages.gz under /main/debian-installer/. The exact error message is:

```
net-retriver: error: MD5 mismatch for main/debian-installer/binary-amd64/Packages.gz (cfa......... != 4c2ecc07.........)
```

I am not sure why I am getting MD5 mismatch error when I synced the local repos with "cobbler reposync". Any insight would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question. Whenever you are creating repos in cobbler, you have to specify which apt components and dists you are going to download and sync.

[image]

I had to add **main, restricted, universe, multiverse, main/debian-installer, restricted/debian-installer** to **Apt Components** and **trusty, trusty-updates, trusty-security, trusty-backports** to **Apt Dist Names** for Ubuntu 14.04 trusty installation to work. These components and lists are required by Ubuntu installation but the automatic ubuntu import feature of cobbler

```
cobbler-ubuntu-import trusty-x86_64
```

does not add the necessary components and lists.